# bgcolor animation using jquery

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-ui

im using jquery animation for the first time.i have read that animation can be done on .Toggle() or.click() functions but i want to suppose chage a bgcolor of a div on page load. i tried it but its not working here is my code.

```
<html> 
<head>   
<scriptsrc="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
 <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4/jquery.min.js">
</script>   
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/jquery- ui.min.js">
</script>

<script>   $(document).ready(function(){ 
$('block').animate({ backgroundColor: "black" }, 1000);   
});   
</script>   
<style>   
.block { 
color: white;
background-color: #68BFEF;
width: 150px; 
height: 70px;
margin: 10px;    }   
</style> 
</head> <body >   
<div class="block"> hi</div>
 </body> 
</html>
```

Comment: got it!  my code had an error i was using $('block') instead of $('.block').its running fine and not a issue of plugin at all.

Comment: thanks everyone for helping..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The animation works, your jQuery selector is wrong.

```
$('.block').animate({ backgroundColor: "black" }, 1000);
```

Notice the '.' in front of 'block'. You were selecting all elements named block (<block>). With the '.', all elements with the class 'block' get selected.

Comment: yeah but animation will take place at each time i refresh the page .is it not possible to restrict at first time only?

Comment: Then you will have to set a flag somewhere to remember you've done the animation already. The HTML5 `Web Storage` feature allows you to do this. For older browsers that do not support this feature, set a cookie or set a JavaScript variable from server-side script.

Answer (score 1):

jQuery can't animate colors by default. You can download a plugin such as [jQuery UI](http://jqueryui.com/demos/animate/) or [Color Animation Plugin](http://www.bitstorm.org/jquery/color-animation/) to have that feature available.